# Accessing mapped network drive from ColdFusion

Tags: windows, networking, file, coldfusion

I am having a problem accessing a mapped drive in ColdFusion. I have `\\server\files\sharing` mapped to `z:\`.  If I run this code, it says the directory exists for the full path but not for the mapped one:

```
<cfscript>
  fullPath = "\\server\files\sharing\reports";
  mappedPath = "z:\reports";

  WriteOutput("fullPath exists: #DirectoryExists(fullPath)#<br/>"); //YES
  WriteOutput("mappedPath exists: #DirectoryExists(mappedPath)#");  //NO
</cfscript>
```

I have done some Googling and have found a few people with the same problem, but the solution was always to use the full path.  Is there a reason ColdFusion wouldn't be able to see or access the mapped drive? And if so, are there any workarounds (maybe a system call to get the full path of the mapped drive)?

Comment: What user is the ColdFusion service running under?

Comment: @AlEverett: it's running as a system service. task manager shows it as "SYSTEM"

Comment: That's likely the problem. Virtually all trouble I've ever had with CF and accessing drives is because "SYSTEM" has very limited access to drive resources. You need to have it run as a user that has access to that drive/directory.

Comment: @AlEverett: but system has access to it if i use the fully qualified name (i.e. \\server\dir). it only fails for the mapped drive, which i though was just like an alias. (maybe i'm missing something fundamental about how mapping network paths to drive letters works...)

Comment: Okay, but what were the results when you tried Al's suggestion (ie running CF under the same user account that mapped the drive)?

Comment: From my understanding, SYSTEM never has access to mapped drives, even if the mapping points to the local system.  Try creating a user with access to the mapping, and run CF under that user.

Comment: Al and Ben are correct. I think mapped drives belong to whatever user they were created under. If you make the CF App server run as that user, accessing the mapped drives should work. Otherwise, you may have to stick with the "\\server\dir" syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why ColdFusion does not have access to the mapped drive is because it runs as a service in Windows.

> A service (or any process that is
>   running in a different security
>   context) that must access a remote
>   resource should use the Universal
>   Naming Convention (UNC) name to access
>   the resource.

That was pulled from the following knowledge-base article:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180362

You may be able to change the service to run as an individual user that has the drives mapped (I haven't checked if that works, but it might), but you should be using the UNC path instead of the mapped drive.